# Structuring function calls in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, functional-programming

I am at a loss in how to structure function calls. I know that the "clean code rules" say that functions should do only ONE thing and that you should keep them as small as possible. So I do.

But I am unsure of how to call these functions. I don't know how to name the concepts, but I am struggling to choose between "calling functions inside of functions" or "chaining/piping functions". In the example below I have a very basic example, but I hope it makes the concepts I talk about clear.

"Chaining/Piping" makes the code easier to unit test, you don't need to mock functions. But "Calling inside functions" makes the code shorter and maybe more readable.

How do you choose between one way or the other?

By the way, I am having a hard time searching for the diffference between the concepts, if someone could point me to a good source - that would be great.

```
# Calling inside a function

def sum_of_squares(numbers):
    return sum([square(num) for num in numbers])

def square(num):
    return num*num

numbers = [2,3,4]
square_sum = sum_of_squares(numbers))

print(square_sum) # prints 29

-----

# Chaining/Piping

def sum_of_squares(squares):
    return sum(squares)

def square(num):
    return num*num

numbers = [2,3,4]
squares = [ square(num) for num in numbers ]
square_sum = sum_of_squares(squares))

print(square_sum) # prints 29
```

Comment: A function doesn't need to do only one thing, it can do multiple simple things, what's more important is that it doesn't (normally) mix procedural calls (e.g. writing to a file) with useful return values.

Comment: The second way is objectively bad, because `sum_of_squares` is simply a badly-named `sum`. This is completely unrelated to unit testing.

Comment: For your example a single function would be ok, or else go with the top one (the bottom one is simply `sum_of_squares = sum` pointless

Comment: `def sum_of_squares(numbers): return sum(num*num for num in numbers)` would be just fine- of course for less trivial examples, breaking up the code makes sense

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I am more interested in the different kind of (made-up?) concepts. Maybe the example is too basic and I should post my code at the code review exchange.

Comment: @JellevanderZwaag Example code is off-topic on Code Review. Maybe you're looking for [SoftwareEngineering.SE]? However, see their [on-topic rules](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before you post there.

Comment: There isn't a hard rule for this stuff, but a bunch of heuristics. Do the simplest thing first. If it's hard to test, split it up. If you find you want to write `sum_of_cubes` as well, factoring out a non-trivial top-level algorithm as eg. `sum(squares(n))` and `sum(cubes(n))` may be reasonable. You can just go through cycles of sketching things, making them testable, combining and de-duplicating some things, and splitting up others.

Comment: @Zeta when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

Basically both type of declarations is good and usable. 
You can choose one or the other depending on what you want to achieve and depending of the context. 
One of the most important aspect is the **transparency** or **readability** of code.
You always should find the **trade-off** between the two type of declarations.

If you write your code in one (or a few) function, the main stream of your code will be pretty transparent and clear, however if anybody (or just you yourself) need to read and interpret your code, you will have to always jump back to the function declarations, then if you have an other function call inside that function, then go further and so on, which could be pretty inconvenient and more likely you will lost the line after a while.

On the other side if you "chain" a lot of function call, like the second way you did, then the front part, main stream of the code will grow and will became less transparent after a while. My key rule of thumb that always keep in "front" what is really enough to understand your code lately and always choose some straightforward **self-explanatory function naming** convention to be able read well your code later.

Another aspect that if you want to use the same sequence of codes you should do it in a function. In this case you will prefer the first way obviously.

I hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the idea of clean code means keeping the code consistent and readable for others. Here's what I think would make a code clean and readable.

> Anyone who hasn't worked on the code or doesn't have prior knowledge
>   about what the code does should be able to understand what the end
>   result will the code give upon running it without you having to
>   explain them what your code does.

So, for me a square function is unnecessary. `number * number` is self explanatory.

So my sum of squares will be

```
numbers = [2, 3, 4]
square_sum = sum(number * number for number in numbers)
```

OR if you need a square function

```
numbers = [2, 3, 4]
sqaureFunction = lambda number: number * number
square_sum = sum(map(sqaureFunction, numbers))
```

In small programs like this it doesn't matter and you shouldn't spend time breaking your head on clean code because this program is not doing anything much. So, I am gonna take a larger example to explain this...

Imagine that you're writing a HTML parser using beautiful soup for extracting information from a website which was my use case. Here's what you algorithm will look like in abstraction.

- Download HTML from the website.
- Give it to HTML Parsers like bs4 or lxml.
- Navigate through each labels in the HTML soup and extract information.
- Store it.

Now for the detailed part,

Part 1 of HTML parsing: The Extraction

- First, start with getting URL of the website for extraction
- Gather information required Headers and post data to get actual information
- Make a request to the website with necessary headers and payload which give you back the HTML
- Write the HTML to a file so that you can reuse it without making multiple requests every time you test.

Part 2 of the HTML parsing: The Parser

- Load the HTML from the file
- Navigate in the HTML and get required data
- Store the information in database or file.

Lastly, the code:

I am just going to write code for extraction part here. See **makeHttpRequest function's documentation** to **understand clean code concept**

```
def makeGetRequest(url, headers = []):
    # You may want to preprocess. Add default headers, etc ... which are specific to the site.
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
    return response

def makeHttpRequest(url, method = "GET", headers = [], payload = {}):
    """
    This function makes an HTTP request.

    You may wanna do several requests before getting the actual information.
    But every time you're going to call make request because it does one thing i.e. Making a request. 
    There can be 101 things that can happen inside this function. 
    But on the outlook, it is just making a single request which can considered as 1 task.
    """
    # You may wanna do POST, PUT, PATCH. But this is just for giving general idea
    if method == "GET":
        response = makeGetRequest(url, headers=headers)
        return response.text
    return None

def extractor(storageFilename):
    """
    This function will make HTTP request and get HTML data.
    After getting HTML data it will store it in a file.
    """
    (url, headers, payload) = loadRequestInformation()
    html = makeHttpRequest(url, headers=headers, payload=payload)
    with open(storageFilename) as htmlFileHandle:
        htmlFileHandle.write(html)
```

Comment: I like the way you use a bigger example to explain the concepts here. However, you should watch out for using mutable values as default arguments - that is a [common gotcha](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) that you should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have functions ready for chaining/Piping then you could have another function wrapping all the function to achieve a certain task providing higher level abstraction for the caller.